# How to set up full access to the shared folders in Linux?

Tags: python, linux, virtualbox, shutil

everyone.
I run Linux python scripts under Linux virtual machine. There are a few shared folders between host and guest system. Script works with files in folder mounted to guest file system through VirtualBox Tools. I have changed access mode to all files and directories in this folder. Other programs (e.g. MatLab) have full access (create or delete any file) to shared file system if I run it under super user. Python returns this error when I run `shutil.rmtree(path)`:

`OSError: [Errno 26] Text file busy`

How can I share my folders without the similar problems?

Details:
Guest - Linux Ubuntu 18.04
Host - Windows 10
VirtualBox version 6.1.6 r137129
Python 3.6

Comment: Is this related to this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40403502/oerror-errno-26-text-file-busy-myvirtualenv-bin-python

Comment: No, I have a different problem. It is occurred only in operations with shared files and folders.

Answer (score 0):

I get this problem as well with shared directories. To my knowledge, there is only one solution to this: don't work with executable files in shared directories.

My understanding of the problem is that the guest operating system is trying to run your command on that file/directory while the host operating system is currently doing something with it via VirtualBox. I don't know the specifics on what exactly VirtualBox is doing in this context, but I suspect it has something to do with synchronizing the content of the files back to the host.

Probably not the answer you were hoping for, but virtual machines are meant to be entirely self-contained, so using shared directories should probably be avoided. If your code is version controlled using something like Git, try cloning the repository into the virtual machine instead.